# Activesupport error when Installing "CocoaPods" using sudo gem install cocoapods

Tags: flutter, rubygems, cocoapods

ERROR:

> Error installing cocoapods:  The last version of activesupport (>=
> 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.3. Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.3` and then running the
> current command again     activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0.
> The current ruby version is 2.6.8.205.

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 37):

try running these command, it'll work.

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.3
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 16):

Cocoapods can by installed via [brew](https://brew.sh/): `brew install cocoapods`

brew will also install latest ruby version as a dependency
and `flutter doctor` is happy about cocoapods after this

Comment: Does not work, downvoted

Comment: worked for me! I was exhausted trying to find what was wrong with gems and active support. but God bless brew

Comment: The KMP page recommends against using brew to install cocoapods:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html#7ad9f30e

Answer (score 0):

use `rbenv` or `rvm` to install a ruby version >= 2.7

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your current `ruby` version is not compatible with the `activesupport` needed version.

##### ✅ RECOMMENDED Method:

So as it suggested you should update your ruby  by using this command:

```
brew upgrade ruby
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
brew link --overwrite ruby
```

Then **restart the Terminal** (make sure you terminate all instances, quit and open again)

Then you can `gem install cocoapods` again and you're good to go.

---

#### Recommended Followup:

It's not required but you can run the following after upgrading the ruby to update gem files:

```
gem update --system 3.4.2
```

---

⚠️ It's not finished yet to use cocoapods:

Besides upgrading ruby, since cocoapods has a known issue, you need to [**follow this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77257297/5623035) and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to use sudo to install it. Just run:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

After succesful installation, run:

```
brew link cocoapods
```

This should work.

However, if you get an error like this:
"Error: Could not symlink bin/xcodeproj, Target /usr/local/bin/xcodeproj already exists", you can overwrite it using:

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

I chose to overwrite because if the already existing file was properly installed/linked, I wouldn't be getting any error in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

This work for me. Iwork whit Flutter 3.12 and Dart 3.1

1.) I delete all plugin for Java in Visual Code, and restart yhe IDE
2.) I do @deema-khaled say:
Try
sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.3
sudo gem install cocoapods
And restart again..

I hope help u!

Answer (score -1):

I was wondering why people does not use the `brew install cocoapods`command it solves almost all the issues related to cocoapods installation using `sudo gem install cocoapods` I have used brew command and it worked for me like a charm.

Although it required to overwrite the `/usr/local/bin/xcodeproj` file. I did it and all is well now. I will attach screen shot bellow.
[image]
[image]