# After updating Cocoapods to 1.13.0 it throws error

Tags: ios, ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I updated CocoaPods to version `1.13.0`. Now, when I run `pod install`, it throws the following error:

```
conversions.rb:108:in '<class:Array>': undefined method 'deprecator' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)
```

How can I fix it?

Here's the full error:

```
bundler: failed to load command: pod (/opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/pod)
/opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:108:in `<class:Array>': undefined method `deprecator' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)

  deprecate to_default_s: :to_s, deprecator: ActiveSupport.deprecator
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
Did you mean?  deprecate_constant
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/pod:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:492:in `exec'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.10/libexec/bundle:45:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.10/libexec/bundle:33:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/bin/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: related? [MacOS react native error bundler: failed to load command: pod](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77237435/12846804)

Comment: @OCa yes, the same issue

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This happens with the installation of CocoaPods version `1.13.0`. The issue has been reported in the CocoaPods project [here](https://%20https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12080).

You can fix the issue by downgrading the [activesupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) gem to version `7.0.8`. Run the following command in Terminal to begin with:

```bash
sudo gem uninstall activesupport
```

This may ask you to select the version to uninstall. Select the version if so.

Then install the version which works by running the following command in Terminal:

```bash
sudo gem install activesupport -v 7.0.8
```

Comment: I use `asdf` and local gem so no need `sudo` `gem uninstall activesupport` `gem install activesupport -v 7.0.8` and modify Gemfile to `gem 'activesupport', '~> 7.0', '>= 7.0.8'`

Comment: I actually kind of did what both you said, so when I tried to uninstall activesupport, it throws me a dangerous warning that there are dependencies and if I'm sure to uninstall it, I didn't uninstall it,  so here what I did I installed directly by 
`sudo gem install activesupport -v 7.0.8`
and THEN I executed the uninstall command
`sudo gem uninstall activesupport`
and it listed me the versions that I want to uninstall, I picked the last version.
for me that is the SAFEST way.

Comment: I tired still facing issue in my MacBook. Getting same error while doing pod install or pod --version

Comment: @ganeshmanoj What is the activesupport version you have?

Comment: Thanks @Danushkaherath now its working fine. I uninstalled all and reinstalled all with latest version ruby 3.2, and problem is with cocoapods activesupport coming with version 7.1.1 so changed to version 7.0.8

Answer (score 31):

Looks like Cocoapods uses `activesupport` without specifying exact version and last release (7.1.0) has a bug.

Found **workaround**. Limit to last *stable* version of `activesupport` (7.0.8).

```
gem 'activesupport', '~> 7.0', '<= 7.0.8'
```

Comment: You missed install keyword. 
gem install 'activesupport', '~> 7.0', '<= 7.0.8'

Comment: This approach to add it to gemfile for CI. But you’re right

Answer (score 13):

Add this line to Gemfile of your project folder

```
gem 'activesupport', '~> 7.0.8'
```

1. `cd ios` to navigate to the ios folder.
2. `bundle install` to install Bundler
3. `bundle update activesupport` to update version of active support
4. `bundle exec pod install` to install the iOS dependencies managed by CocoaPods.

Answer (score 8):

My solution is to replace original `gem 'cocoapods'` with this below in Gemfile in root directory.

```
gem 'cocoapods', '~> 1.12'
gem 'activesupport', '>= 6.1.7.3', '< 7.1.0'
```

Then, `cd ios` to enter in ios folder and run these below. And it will work like before. I am not familiar with this part. Maybe some commands are not necessary. but it worked for me.

```
1. bundle update
2. bundle install
3. pod repo update
4. bundle exec pod install
```

Comment: For a Flutter I fixed it with: 1. open `Gemfile` in iOS folder 2. Add: `gem "cocoapods", '~> 1.12.1' gem` and `'activesupport', '~> 7.0.8'`

Answer (score 5):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/12082) and has been [**fixed**](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/commit/216478820851e7feed9fa512b8183808c57b6cb2) by the cocoapods team but not released yet.

You can fix it easily by adding 1 line of code until the next release:

1. Open `/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods.rb` with the [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) or something.
2. Add `require 'active_support'` on line 7 above other 'require active_support/...`.

[image: Demo]

3. (sudo) Save the file and run `gem install cocoapods` again.

---

<sub>It's not required and related to this issue but you can also update your ruby and gem files [**following this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77256967/5623035) to prevent furthur errors</sub>

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in cocoapods version 1.14.0. If there's no issue for you to install this version of cocoapods, best to upgrade it as it's much easier than to adjust the activesupport version.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.14.0

add in gemfile:

```
gem 'cocoapods', '= 1.14.0'
```

then run `bundle install`