# MacOS react native error bundler: failed to load command: pod

Tags: ios, ruby, react-native, macos, cocoapods

I tried creating a new project in react native:

```
 npx react-native@latest init myApp
```

[image]

```
> gem which cocoapods

/Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods.rb
```

When creating the project I get this:

```
Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error bundler: failed to load command: pod (/Users/nameUser/Desktop/proj/myApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/pod)
/Users/nameUser/Desktop/proj/myApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:108:in `<class:Array>': undefined method `deprecator' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)

  deprecate to_default_s: :to_s, deprecator: ActiveSupport.deprecator
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
Did you mean?  deprecate_constant
    from /Users/nameUser/Desktop/proj/myApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from /Users/nameUser/Desktop/proj/myApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from /Users/nameUser/Desktop/proj/myApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nameUser/Desktop/proj/myApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    from /Users/nameUser/Desktop/proj/myApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/pod:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:492:in `exec'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.20/exe/bundle:37:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.20/exe/bundle:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    from /Users/nameUser/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: related? [After updating Cocoapods to 1.13.0 it throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77236339/12846804)

Answer (score 5):

I'm also experiencing this, under an older version of Ruby.  I think it's related to this recent commit to the `react-native` repo:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/ce39931bc2b02f13cbc5751ba4d4a6dbc07bc91a

I think I've got a workaround while this is addressed (unless there's some new prerequisite that's not documented, I'm not au fait with the Ruby ecosystem)

The command that's failing, after checking the `@react-native-community/cli` package, is `bundle exec pod install`.

If you re-run the init project command, let it fail, then `cd YourProjectName/ios/ && pod install`, it *should* work for you as if the official installer completed successfully.

From there you can `yarn start` and run the application on iOS, Android etc.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a bug in a new version of `activesupport`. You can downgrade until you find the right version. You will probably have to update your Podfile formatting to match the different version.

For example:

```
gem uninstall activesupport -v 7.1.1
gem install activesupport -v  7.0.8
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also having the issue and following worked for me. I just downgraded cocoapods and activesupport.

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.12.1
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -v 1.13.0
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core -v 1.13.0
$ sudo gem install activesupport -v 7.0.8
$ sudo gem uninstall activesupport -v 7.1.1
$ pod --version
1.12.1
```

- https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12081
- https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/12082

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it based on this [PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/ce39931bc2b02f13cbc5751ba4d4a6dbc07bc91a) adding the following line to my Gemfile

```
gem 'activesupport', '>= 6.1.7.3', '< 7.1.0'
```

Then rerunning `pod install`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `npx react-native doctor` for such errors. Helps identify the source of errors and find solutions

Answer (score 0):

> `gem 'activesupport', '>= 6.1.7.3', '< 7.1.0'`

The suggestion from Mike S. solved the issue for me, with one small change.  I had to run `bundle install exec pod install` before subsequent `pod install` commands would work.